# How to log variables in an API made with CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, web-applications

I am debugging, remotely, an API built with CodeIgniter framework by previous programmers. I programmed with other PHP MVC frameworks, but I never built an API before (nor used CodeIgniter), and debuging a variable was always as easy as **echo**, **var_dump**, **print_r**, ...or just use the framework's log commands.

Now, I don't have a page to display errors and logs on it (or do I?), I tried **log_message**, **error_log**, and **put_file_contents** without any luck! It only runs the first log command but the second one doesn't!

In my **model** I have the following function:

```
public function processcontacts($data) {
        error_log(json_encode($data), 3, "~/logs/processcontacts_data.txt");
        $countryCode = $data["countryCode"];
        error_log(json_encode($countryCode), 3, "~/logs/processcontacts_countryCode.txt");
        $isContact = array();
        $isNotContact = array();
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

                $value->phone = str_replace(" ", "", $value->phone);
                $value->name = str_replace(" undefined", "", $value->name);
                $value->name = str_replace(" Undefined", "", $value->name);
                $query = $this->db->get_where('appusers', array(
                    'id' => $this->getMyId($value->phone, $countryCode)
                        )
                );
                if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                    $row = $query->row();
                    $value->country = $row->country;
                    if ($row->photoapproved == 1) {
                        $value->photo = $row->photo;
                    }
                    $value->token = $row->token;
                    array_push($isContact, $value);
                } else {
                    array_push($isNotContact, $value);
                }
            }

        $returner = array();
        $returner["isMember"] = $isContact;
        $returner["isNotMember"] = $isNotContact;
        return json_encode($returner);
    }
```

I have two error_log (or put_file_contents) yet only one shows up and nothing after that! Any possibilities what could be the cause of this and **how to track it**?

Comment: There is a hook in codeigniter. You can create a hook that can be invoked before or after routing and catch any errors happening after that point.

Comment: Are you aware that they write to different files?

Comment: You can try to make the requests with Postman - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en and just `var_dump()` what you want.

Comment: @xpuc7o your idea sounds interesting. Do you know how to attach json file data to it?

Comment: @u_mulder yes I do! I made it like that on purpose.

Comment: @trust_words you do not need to attach a json file just `var_dump($myVar); exit;` and Postman will show you the result (like in a browser).

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter has some error logging functions built in:

- Make your /application/logs folder writable
- In `/application/config/config.php` set:

  `$config['log_threshold'] = 1;`

There are multiple levels of logging like this:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Error Logging Threshold
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You can enable error logging by setting a threshold over zero. The
| threshold determines what gets logged. Threshold options are:
|
|   0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
|   1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
|   2 = Debug Messages
|   3 = Informational Messages
|   4 = All Messages
|
| You can also pass an array with threshold levels to show individual error types
|
|   array(2) = Debug Messages, without Error Messages
|
| For a live site you'll usually only enable Errors (1) to be logged otherwise
| your log files will fill up very fast.
|
*/
$config['log_threshold'] = 4;
```

For more reference see [CodeIgniter Error Handling](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html)

> **UPDATED**
>
> The log filename in the configuration settings needs a trailing "/"
> making sure the webserver process has writeable access to the
> directory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have it configured just like that. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was not configuring the right php.ini file! The one needed to be modified is the one inside '../apache2/..'

However, I really found out that **[Postman](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman)** is a great tool for debugging remote API so I wanted to point it out here for attention. (thanks to @xpuc7o)